# 1 UIViewController and 2 switching UIViews programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am bit stack with creating two UIViews which are switchable (each UIView has some of subviews). Since I do not IB, I wanna do that programmatically.

I have tried adding my subviews to my first UIView, then the same with second one and then switching to view like this.

```
 if ([self.setView superview]) {
  [self.setView removeFromSuperview];
  [self.view addSubview:contentView];
        self.navigationItem.title = @"BaseLine";
 } else {
  [self.contentView removeFromSuperview];
  self.view = setView;
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Settings";
 }
```

but only thing which works correctly was "title" and nothing appeared on the UIViews. The UIView seems to be OK because when I use

```
self.view = contentView;
or
self.view = setView;
```

both showing subviews correctly.

Pls someone kick me to the right direction about this.

tnx

EDIT:
Also pointing the solution, perhaps something wrong with my initialization in the loadView

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];
    setView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];

    self.view = contentView;
```

I tried to add it first [self. view add..] but the app crashed, so I used this

EDIT2

the root controller is UITableViewController..it is in navigation view and after choosing a cell this UIVieController (percView) with two UIVies is allocated

```
     ShakeControl *percView = [[ShakeControl alloc] init];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:percView animated:YES];
     [percView release];
```

EDIT3
switch is done by button, but it is fine done because I used that many times and it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of a view controller that does what you want (I think).  It is very basic, just switching between two views with different color backgrounds.  But, you could further customize those subviews in the loadView method to display whatever you need.

The interface file:

```
@interface SwapViewController : UIViewController {
    UIView *firstView;
    UIView *secondView;
    BOOL displayingFirstView;
    UIButton *swapButton;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *firstView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *secondView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *swapButton;

- (void)swap;

@end
```

The implementation file:

```
#import "SwapViewController.h"

@implementation SwapViewController

@synthesize firstView;
@synthesize secondView;
@synthesize swapButton;

- (void)loadView 
{
    CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

    UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    containerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.view = containerView;
    [containerView release];

    frame = self.view.bounds;
    firstView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    firstView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    secondView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    secondView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    self.swapButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    self.swapButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50);
    [swapButton addTarget:self action:@selector(swap) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    displayingFirstView = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:firstView];
    [self.view addSubview:swapButton];
}

- (void)swap
{
    if(displayingFirstView) {
        [self.firstView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view addSubview:secondView];

        displayingFirstView = NO;
    } else {
        [self.secondView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view addSubview:firstView];

        displayingFirstView = YES;
    }
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.swapButton];
}

@end
```

Comment: That is the code what I originally thought that works but does not.

Comment: Have you initialized self.view by overriding loadView?  Assuming self.view is not nil, is its frame sized and positioned correctly?

Comment: yes i am overriding loadView and self.view has view with applicationFrame size

Comment: How is this view controller displayed?  Is it the root view controller?  Is it in a navigation controller?  Also, how is the view switched, a UIButton?  Can you post any more of you view controller class?

Comment: containerView release]; caused that app crashed but when I remove the release  those two UIView allocation were mixed up together...man I have not thought that it is possible :o), but I think it is somehow else

Comment: So the conclusion is when I need two UIView, actually I need to allocate 3. Thank you a lot. Works perfectly

Comment: Yes, the third view is always visible, occupying the space that you want to fill with the other views.  Those other views are displayed by adding them as subviews of that third "container" view.

Answer (score 0):

sample code;

```
BOOL firstview = YES; // First, I have added view1 as a subview;

if (firstview) {
  [view1 removeFromSuperview];
  [self.view addSubview:view2];
 } else {
  [view2 removeFromSuperview];
  self.view addSubview:view1];
 }
```